# Spyder cannot import certain modules

Tags: spyder

I am on Windows 10 acer laptop. I have downloaded anaconda2 and use it to download packages. With anaconda2 came a spyder installation with an IPython console option. Using the IPython console I am trying to import packages. However, for some of them I get an ImportError. [Spyder Ipython terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN5AV.png)

However when I run conda list I clearly see these packages listed. 
[openblas Clearly Seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFzyc.png)

Comment: Try restarting spyder. It should work.

Comment: Did you find any online script importing them this way? I've just googled a bit, but isn't openblas supposed to improve the speed of NumPy behind the scenes? And is clapack imported like that? I don't think this is a Spyder issue.